# Grails: Inject Service into the Command Object

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have a command class which needs to call a service.

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder as AH

class FilterVisitCommand {

    def accessRightsService = AH.application.mainContext.accessRightsService
    def customerService = AH.application.mainContext.customerService
...
}
```

This kind service definition via application holder is working however is depracated. Is there another way to let the service be injected? Only "def accessRightsService" does not work for the command class.

Comment: Why doesn't `def accessRightsService` work?

Answer (score 15):

If you are injecting a service into a command object for validation, you may need to reference the service via the command object.

```
class FilterVisitCommand {

    def accessRightsService

    static constraints = {
        foo(validator: { foo, cmd ->
            cmd.accessRightsService.bar()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be it, and is exactly how you'd do it in 1.3.x.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how can I access the service in a method which is placed in the command class?

Answer (score 0):

The [Grails rich domain](http://grails.org/plugin/rich-domain) plugin enables service injection, validation, ... for regular Groovy classes.